# Warnings when closing SoftKeyboard manually

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I'm using following code to close the EditText's SoftKeyboard when clicking a button:

```
public void closeSoftInput(){
    final Context c = this.getContext();
    if(c==null)
        return;
    editText.clearFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)c.getSystemService(
              Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}
```

That works fine, but everytime I call closeSoftInput() I get these warnings:

```
10-01 21:55:13.075: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25021): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection

10-01 21:55:13.075: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25021): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection

10-01 21:55:13.075: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25021): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
```

If I close the keyboard by pressing the back-key no warnings a thrown.
Why are they thrown when I execute closeSoftInput()?

Thx

Comment: Are you using an `InputConnection` with the text typed in?

Comment: nope. I just added a TextWatcher to the editText